# pyqtgraph how to get mouse click position correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I prepared correct  onMouse moved function and it shows correctly coordinates of my mouse, but when I clicked somewhere, python prints coordinates of my window not of my plot. I tried to make it the same like for the onMouseMoved but it doesn't work. I also tried to use mouseClickEvent.scenePos() instead od mouseClickEvent but it also doesn't work.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        hour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        temperature = [30, 32, 34, 32, 33, 31, 29, 32, 35, 45]

        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)

        self.label = pg.TextItem(text="X: {} \nY: {}".format(0, 0))
        self.graphWidget.addItem(self.label)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphWidget.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.onMouseMoved)
        self.graphWidget.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(self.mouse_clicked)

    def onMouseMoved(self, evt):
        if self.graphWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(evt):
            point = self.graphWidget.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(evt)
            self.label.setHtml(
                "<p style='color:white'>X： {0} <br> Y: {1}</p>". \
                    format(point.x(), point.y()))

    def mouse_clicked(self, mouseClickEvent):
        # mouseClickEvent is a pyqtgraph.GraphicsScene.mouseEvents.MouseClickEvent
        print('clicked plot 0x{:x}, event: {}'.format(id(self), mouseClickEvent))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You said "I tried to make it the same like for the onMouseMoved", but that doesn't look like that. Also, why are you using `{:x}`?

Answer (score 2):

Asked question is very legitimate.
Indeed evt object from MouseMoused and MouseClicked is not the same.
For MouseMoved You got `QPoint` and for MouseClicked `MouseClickEvent`.

Reason for that is simple.
How would You know which mouse button was clicked, if You've got only x, y position?

So, to make things works "the same" we need to convert our MouseClickEvent into QPoint.
This can be done with `evt.ScenePos()`

Here is Your modified code:

```
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        hour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        temperature = [30, 32, 34, 32, 33, 31, 29, 32, 35, 45]

        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)

        self.label = pg.TextItem(text="X: {} \nY: {}".format(0, 0))
        self.graphWidget.addItem(self.label)

        self.graphWidget.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouse_moved)
        self.graphWidget.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(self.mouse_clicked)

    def mouse_moved(self, evt):
        vb = self.graphWidget.plotItem.vb
        if self.graphWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(evt):
            mouse_point = vb.mapSceneToView(evt)
            self.label.setHtml(f"<p style='color:white'>X： {mouse_point.x()} <br> Y: {mouse_point.y()}</p>")

    def mouse_clicked(self, evt):
        vb = self.graphWidget.plotItem.vb
        scene_coords = evt.scenePos()
        if self.graphWidget.sceneBoundingRect().contains(scene_coords):
            mouse_point = vb.mapSceneToView(scene_coords)
            print(f'clicked plot X: {mouse_point.x()}, Y: {mouse_point.y()}, event: {evt}')


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This works fine for me